# How to Make my Pyqt web Browser as a Defaut Browser

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am Developing web browser using Pyqt4. Just like other browsers(Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, etc.), I need to ask the user to set my application as the default browser.

Is there a way we can set default browser through code?

Comment: What platform? Just windows (since you mention Internet Explorer) or all platforms that PyQt runs on?

Comment: That will require per-platform native code for sure. Worth to check e.g. chromium or firefox source code to see how they do it.

Comment: We are using the browser in windows platform..

Comment: One answer is for you to read Firefox or Chromium code to understand how they do it. If you have trouble navigating that code, you should ask a separate question that specifically references the repository you're trying to get, and asks a question related to that repository.